# Wildcards not being substituted

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash
loc=`echo ~/.gvfs/*/DCIM/100_FUJI`
rm -f /mnt/fujifilmA100
ln -s "$loc" /mnt/fujifilmA100
```

For some reason the variable * doesn't get substituted with the only possible value and gets given the value /home/chris/.gvfs/*/DCIM/100_FUJI. Does anyone have an idea of why?

Please note:

- If global expansion fails, the pattern is not substituted. I ran the
  commands:

  chris@comp2008:~$ loc=``echo ~/.gvfs/*/DCIM/100_FUJI

  chris@comp2008:~$ echo $loc

  /home/chris/.gvfs/gphoto2 mount on usb%3A001,008/DCIM/100_FUJI

  So we can see the expansion should
  work
- I have now switched to using:

  loc = ``find ~/.gvfs -name 100_FUJI

  I am just curious why it doesn't work as is.
- Debugging output using sh -x

> echo /home/chris/.gvfs/*/DCIM/100_FUJI
>
> loc=/home/chris/.gvfs/*/DCIM/100_FUJI
>
> rm -f /mnt/fujifilmA100
>
> ln -s /home/chris/.gvfs/*/DCIM/100_FUJI/mnt/fujifilmA100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I modified my script as follows:

```
loc=`echo ~chris/.gvfs/*/DCIM/`
sudo rm -f /mnt/camera
sudo ln -s "$loc" /mnt/camera
```

Notice that the sudo's are inside the script

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned in your response to Tactical Vim that you're running this under sudo -- '`~`' is going to be expanded differently under sudo vs. under your normal user.  Change it to '`~chris`' or hard code your home directory.

Comment: Using ~ instead of ~chris did that directory to not be matched properly, but the * still manages to not be replaced

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you entered the .sh file exactly as shown here? I just made a test script doing exactly the same thing as you and it works for me.

Maybe something to do with the strange directory name with spaces, %-signs, and commas?

Comment: That is exactly how it was entered. I checked several times

Answer (score 2):

Try running your script under 'sh -x' to see some debug output, perhaps it'll provide a clue. I've never seen echo used in this sort of way, it could be something related to that; does it work if you replace 'echo' with 'ls -d' (or similar, not sure your output) instead?

Comment: Tried: ls -d ~/.gvfs/*/DCIM/100_FUJI
/home/chris/.gvfs/gphoto2 mount on usb%3A001,003/DCIM/100_FUJI

But when I put ls -d in the script it threw Permission Denied even though I sudoed both the script and the ls

Comment: As yesterday mentioned, ~ expands the the home folder of the user running the command (sic, it's more complicated). Try being explicit and naming the direct folder as he mentions.